# Checking if Android device has 4G or 5G

Tags: android, networking, cellular-network, 4g, 5g

Is it possible to check if an Android device supports 3G, 4G or 5G programmatically? NOT to check what type of network is the device connected to but if the current device is able to use 5G network...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a particular device supports 4G networks in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887840/how-to-check-whether-a-particular-device-supports-4g-networks-in-android) also you didnt mention how you want to check it by code or by phone settings be more clear for us to help you.

Comment: thanks, fixed, ofc programmatically. I've tried your answer suggestion but that is deprecated and doesn't work.

Comment: It might help guide potential answerers to know what about that suggestion doesn't work (I'm not familiar with the APIs in question, though, so I'm not much help here).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the device support 5G like mentioned here

[Check if android adapter supports 5GHz frequency WIFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671437/check-if-android-adapter-supports-5ghz-frequency-wifi)

I guess, the WifiManager is what you are looking for....

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#is5GHzBandSupported()

Comment: I believe OP was asking about mobile connectivity, not Wi-Fi.

Comment: He said 3G, 4G, 5G in mobile network. Not 2,4G or 5G in Wifi